# R language: If and else statement (loop)

Tags: r, function, loops, if-statement

I am working on a loop coding on R language, and this code involves two functions. If value is  radius, period function should be run instead of radius function, and so on.

I coded using my notes from class, but I think it is wrong. I do not get any warnings, but if I do on Console:

```
R<-98
orbit(R)
```

I will get this message:

```
Error in orbit(R) : attempt to apply non-function
```

This is my function code:

```
# Two functions: period and radius
# If a value you input is a period (in minutes), radius function should be used (radius(R))
# If a value you input is a radius (in km), period function should be used (period(R))
#   R is radius in km or period in minutes


orbit <- function(R){
    G <-6.673*10^-11
    M <- 5.972*10^24 # in kg

    if(R == 98){
            omega <- 2*pi/R # pr is period for one rotation

            Radi <- (G*M/omega^3)(1/3)
            print(Radi)
        }
    else {

        Peri <- 2*pi*sqrt(R^3/G*M)
        print(Peri)

    }

}
```

I don't think I fully understand if and else statement. Does anyone explain it for me? Also what is difference between for statement and if statement?

Thank you for all help.

Comment: `Radi <- (G*M/omega^3)(1/3)` this line is missing a `*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in this line

```
Radi <- (G*M/omega^3)*(1/3)
```

where you missing `*` operation

`if/else statement` allows your program to decide which code to execute based on some condition. Like in your code, you have two blocks of code the first one is:

```
omega <- 2*pi/R # pr is period for one rotation
Radi <- (G*M/omega^3)(1/3)
print(Radi)
```

which you want to execute *only* if some condition is true i.e. `R == 98`, otherwise you execute the other block of code.

`for statement` is used when you want to repeatedly execute a block of code many times. Let's say you want to print the numbers from `1-100`, it is not feasible to write `print(1)` `print(2)` ... 100 times!

You do this with a simple `for` loop, e.g.

```
for(i in 1:100){
   print(i)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This makes much sense!